# How to enable or disable Firebase datasynchronization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-synchronization

I am making an app in which I want to make a button from which I can disable or enable Firebase data Synchronization when I am online.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities. Turning off/on the 'keepSynced'' should handle this for you. `(DatabaseReference) reference.keepSynced(true);`

Comment: what you have to do is subclass all your event listeners then you make two methods to add and remover the listeners. this is done so because firebase event listeners synchronise data immediately the event they are added

Answer (score 3):

To disable data synchronization:

1. Either remove all listeners, and then re-attach them to start listening again.
2. Or call `goOffline()` to disable synchronization, and then call `goOnline()` to start synchronizing again.